# React Router Error: You should not use Route outside of Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router

I'm just doing some basic routing in my react app and I've done it this way before so I'm pretty confused to as why it isn't working now.

The error I am getting says: `You should not use <Route> or withRouter() outside a <Router>`

I'm sure this is super basic so thanks for baring with me!

```
import React from 'react'
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import * as BooksAPI from './BooksAPI'
import BookList from './BookList'
import './App.css'

class BooksApp extends React.Component {
  state = {
    books: []
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getBooks()
  }

  getBooks = () => {
    BooksAPI.getAll().then(data => {
      this.setState({
        books: data
      })
    })
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Route exact path="/" render={() => (
          <BookList
            books={this.state.books}
          />
        )}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default BooksApp
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to setup context provider for react-router

```
  import { BrowserRouter, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

  // ....

  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div className="App">
          <Route exact path="/" render={() => (
            <BookList
              books={this.state.books}
            />
          )}/>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    )
  }
```

Side note - `BrowserRouter` should be placed at the top level of your application and have only a single child.

Comment: I would clarify this by also importing the Route to clarify that both are needed. For this use case

`import { BrowserRouter, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';`

Comment: Of course. I completely forgot to add that to my index.js file. So foolish. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the exact same issue. Turns out that i didn't wrap the `App` inside `BrowserRouter` before using the `Route` in App.js.

Here is how i fixed in `index.js`.

```
import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```